# ORDER BY slows query performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, order-by, explain

I see very bad query performance when `ORDER BY` is added

`act.activity_schedule` is a DB view. There are indexes on `date` and `start_hour`.

```
create index activity_schedule_tab_date_index
    on activity_schedule_tab (date);

create index activity_schedule_tab_start_hour_index
    on activity_schedule_tab (start_hour);
```

Take a look on below example:

```
SELECT *
FROM act.activity_schedule ast
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND customer_id = :customer_id
  AND archived = :archived
  AND (ast.deleted = :deleted)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT ac.user_id
              FROM acl.user_access_tab ac
              WHERE ac.user_id = :my_user_id
                AND ac.role_name <> 'PARENT'
                AND ((ac.customer_id = ast.customer_id AND ac.operator_id IS NULL AND ac.facility_id IS NULL) OR
                     (ac.customer_id = ast.customer_id AND ac.operator_id = ast.operator_id AND
                      ac.facility_id IS NULL) OR
                     (ac.customer_id = ast.customer_id AND ac.operator_id = ast.operator_id AND
                      ac.facility_id = ast.facility_id)))
```

Execution Time: 479 ms

Output of `explain (analyse, buffers, format text)`:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.70..1388.52 rows=1 width=583) (actual time=0.946..128948.314 rows=171045 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (a.activity_type_id = att.activity_type_id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 152
  Buffers: shared hit=5558698 read=15799 dirtied=1107 written=3
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.70..1284.59 rows=1 width=485) (actual time=0.397..52944.720 rows=171045 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (ot.operator_id = a.operator_id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2581774
        Buffers: shared hit=1428751 read=9007 dirtied=1107 written=3
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.70..1282.91 rows=1 width=444) (actual time=0.360..30350.003 rows=171045 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=1257706 read=9007 dirtied=1107 written=3
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.41..1280.73 rows=1 width=299) (actual time=0.337..26899.333 rows=171045 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=744574 read=9004 dirtied=1107 written=3
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.14..1280.44 rows=1 width=255) (actual time=0.316..23505.576 rows=171045 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (cd.customer_dic_id = ast.status_id)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2394301
                          Buffers: shared hit=234838 read=9004 dirtied=1107 written=3
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..1279.13 rows=1 width=209) (actual time=0.173..2725.215 rows=171045 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=63793 read=9004 dirtied=1107 written=3
                                ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.71..1272.06 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.140..156.050 rows=4797 loops=1)
                                      Join Filter: (((ac.operator_id IS NULL) AND (ac.facility_id IS NULL)) OR ((ac.operator_id = a.operator_id) AND (ac.facility_id IS NULL)) OR ((ac.operator_id = a.operator_id) AND (ac.facility_id = a.facility_id)))
                                      Buffers: shared hit=50 read=1186 dirtied=85
                                      ->  Index Scan using activity_tab_archived_index on activity_tab a  (cost=0.43..1164.51 rows=4763 width=96) (actual time=0.062..62.014 rows=4797 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (archived = 0)
                                            Filter: ((customer_id = 3) AND (deleted = 0))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 280
                                            Buffers: shared hit=50 read=1183 dirtied=85
                                      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..12.32 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=4797)
                                            Buffers: shared read=3
                                            ->  Index Scan using user_access_tab_user_id_index on user_access_tab ac  (cost=0.29..12.31 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.035..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (user_id = 31)
                                                  Filter: (((role_name)::text <> 'PARENT'::text) AND (customer_id = 3))
                                                  Buffers: shared read=3
                                ->  Index Scan using activity_schedule_tab_activity_id_index on activity_schedule_tab ast  (cost=0.42..6.71 rows=36 width=117) (actual time=0.026..0.244 rows=36 loops=4797)
                                      Index Cond: (activity_id = a.activity_id)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=63743 read=7818 dirtied=1022 written=3
                          ->  Seq Scan on customer_dic_tab cd  (cost=0.00..1.14 rows=14 width=50) (actual time=0.005..0.057 rows=14 loops=171045)
                                Buffers: shared hit=171045
                    ->  Index Scan using instructor_tab_pk on instructor_tab it  (cost=0.27..0.29 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=171045)
                          Index Cond: (instructor_id = ast.instructor_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=509736
              ->  Index Scan using facility_tab_pk on facility_tab ft  (cost=0.29..2.18 rows=1 width=149) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=171045)
                    Index Cond: (facility_id = a.facility_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=513132 read=3
        ->  Seq Scan on operator_tab ot  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=30 width=45) (actual time=0.005..0.060 rows=16 loops=171045)
              Buffers: shared hit=171045
  ->  Seq Scan on activity_type_tab att  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=44) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=171045)
        Buffers: shared hit=171045
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on calendar_tab ct  (cost=0.00..84.71 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.373..0.373 rows=0 loops=169912)
"          Filter: ((customer_id = a.customer_id) AND ((type)::text = 'AVAIL'::text) AND (user_id = it.user_id) AND ((ast.date + ast.start_hour) >= start) AND ((ast.date + ast.start_hour) <= ""end"") AND ((ast.date + ast.end_hour) >= start) AND ((ast.date + ast.end_hour) <= ""end""))"
          Rows Removed by Filter: 1699
          Buffers: shared hit=3568134
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=18.08..18.09 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.033..0.036 rows=1 loops=171045)
          Buffers: shared hit=390768 read=6792
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on schedule_report_tab srt  (cost=6.31..18.08 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.020 rows=0 loops=171045)
                Recheck Cond: (activity_schedule_id = ast.activity_schedule_id)
                Heap Blocks: exact=55393
                Buffers: shared hit=390768 read=6792
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on schedule_report_tab_activity_schedule_id_index  (cost=0.00..6.31 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=171045)
                      Index Cond: (activity_schedule_id = ast.activity_schedule_id)
                      Buffers: shared hit=341898 read=252
Planning Time: 5.889 ms
Execution Time: 129681.159 ms
```

However if I add `ORDER BY`, performance gets much worse:

```
SELECT *
FROM act.activity_schedule ast
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND customer_id = :customer_id
  AND archived = :archived
  AND (ast.deleted = :deleted)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT ac.user_id
              FROM acl.user_access_tab ac
              WHERE ac.user_id = :my_user_id
                AND ac.role_name <> 'PARENT'
                AND ((ac.customer_id = ast.customer_id AND ac.operator_id IS NULL AND ac.facility_id IS NULL) OR
                     (ac.customer_id = ast.customer_id AND ac.operator_id = ast.operator_id AND
                      ac.facility_id IS NULL) OR
                     (ac.customer_id = ast.customer_id AND ac.operator_id = ast.operator_id AND
                      ac.facility_id = ast.facility_id)))
ORDER BY ast.date ASC, ast.start_hour ASC
```

Execution Time: 127880 ms

Output of `explain (analyse, buffers, format text)`:

```
Sort  (cost=1388.53..1388.53 rows=1 width=573) (actual time=122353.256..123129.373 rows=171045 loops=1)
"  Sort Key: ast.date, ast.start_hour"
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 68992kB
"  Buffers: shared hit=5562276 read=12522 dirtied=720 written=3, temp read=27456 written=27550"
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.70..1388.52 rows=1 width=573) (actual time=0.811..120815.335 rows=171045 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (a.activity_type_id = att.activity_type_id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 152
        Buffers: shared hit=5562276 read=12522 dirtied=720 written=3
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.70..1284.59 rows=1 width=475) (actual time=0.379..51058.359 rows=171045 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (ot.operator_id = a.operator_id)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2581774
              Buffers: shared hit=1430820 read=7238 dirtied=720 written=1
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.70..1282.91 rows=1 width=434) (actual time=0.344..29508.491 rows=171045 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1259775 read=7238 dirtied=720 written=1
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.41..1280.73 rows=1 width=289) (actual time=0.300..26280.907 rows=171045 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=746652 read=7226 dirtied=720 written=1
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.14..1280.44 rows=1 width=245) (actual time=0.277..22787.269 rows=171045 loops=1)
                                Join Filter: (cd.customer_dic_id = ast.status_id)
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2394301
                                Buffers: shared hit=236916 read=7226 dirtied=720 written=1
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..1279.13 rows=1 width=199) (actual time=0.153..2625.467 rows=171045 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=65871 read=7226 dirtied=720 written=1
                                      ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.71..1272.06 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.113..152.228 rows=4797 loops=1)
                                            Join Filter: (((ac.operator_id IS NULL) AND (ac.facility_id IS NULL)) OR ((ac.operator_id = a.operator_id) AND (ac.facility_id IS NULL)) OR ((ac.operator_id = a.operator_id) AND (ac.facility_id = a.facility_id)))
                                            Buffers: shared hit=50 read=1186 dirtied=4
                                            ->  Index Scan using activity_tab_archived_index on activity_tab a  (cost=0.43..1164.51 rows=4763 width=96) (actual time=0.058..61.403 rows=4797 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (archived = 0)
                                                  Filter: ((customer_id = 3) AND (deleted = 0))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 280
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=49 read=1184 dirtied=4
                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..12.32 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=4797)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
                                                  ->  Index Scan using user_access_tab_user_id_index on user_access_tab ac  (cost=0.29..12.31 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.031..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (user_id = 31)
                                                        Filter: (((role_name)::text <> 'PARENT'::text) AND (customer_id = 3))
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
                                      ->  Index Scan using activity_schedule_tab_activity_id_index on activity_schedule_tab ast  (cost=0.42..6.71 rows=36 width=107) (actual time=0.023..0.231 rows=36 loops=4797)
                                            Index Cond: (activity_id = a.activity_id)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=65821 read=6040 dirtied=716 written=1
                                ->  Seq Scan on customer_dic_tab cd  (cost=0.00..1.14 rows=14 width=50) (actual time=0.005..0.054 rows=14 loops=171045)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=171045
                          ->  Index Scan using instructor_tab_pk on instructor_tab it  (cost=0.27..0.29 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=171045)
                                Index Cond: (instructor_id = ast.instructor_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=509736
                    ->  Index Scan using facility_tab_pk on facility_tab ft  (cost=0.29..2.18 rows=1 width=149) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=171045)
                          Index Cond: (facility_id = a.facility_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=513123 read=12
              ->  Seq Scan on operator_tab ot  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=30 width=45) (actual time=0.005..0.058 rows=16 loops=171045)
                    Buffers: shared hit=171045
        ->  Seq Scan on activity_type_tab att  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=44) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=171045)
              Buffers: shared hit=171045
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Seq Scan on calendar_tab ct  (cost=0.00..84.71 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.342..0.342 rows=0 loops=169912)
"                Filter: ((customer_id = a.customer_id) AND ((type)::text = 'AVAIL'::text) AND (user_id = it.user_id) AND ((ast.date + ast.start_hour) >= start) AND ((ast.date + ast.start_hour) <= ""end"") AND ((ast.date + ast.end_hour) >= start) AND ((ast.date + ast.end_hour) <= ""end""))"
                Rows Removed by Filter: 1699
                Buffers: shared hit=3568134
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=18.08..18.09 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.030..0.034 rows=1 loops=171045)
                Buffers: shared hit=392277 read=5284 written=2
                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on schedule_report_tab srt  (cost=6.31..18.08 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=0 loops=171045)
                      Recheck Cond: (activity_schedule_id = ast.activity_schedule_id)
                      Heap Blocks: exact=55394
                      Buffers: shared hit=392277 read=5284 written=2
                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on schedule_report_tab_activity_schedule_id_index  (cost=0.00..6.31 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=171045)
                            Index Cond: (activity_schedule_id = ast.activity_schedule_id)
                            Buffers: shared hit=341920 read=230
Planning Time: 7.207 ms
Execution Time: 123808.963 ms
```

Comment: The first query shows 479ms when executes directly and 129 seconds in explain analyze, which is about the same time as the second one... Was there a problem during copypaste? Also you need to post the view definition, it's impossible to understand what the EXPLAIN tables refer to without it

Comment: The root cause for the bad estimates are the `OR` in the `WHERE` condition of the `EXISTS` subquery. Perhaps you can split it into three distinct queries and `UNION` them. As a workaround, you can `SET enable_nestloop = off;` for the duration of that query, and I bet the performance will improve.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is convoluted, that's the primary issue. Straighten it out first:

```
SELECT *
FROM   act.activity_schedule a
WHERE  a.customer_id = :customer_id
AND    a.archived = :archived
AND    a.deleted = :deleted
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM acl.user_access_tab ac
   WHERE  ac.user_id = :my_user_id
   AND    ac.role_name <> 'PARENT'
   AND    ac.customer_id = :customer_id  -- !!!
   AND  ((ac.operator_id IS NULL         AND ac.facility_id IS NULL) OR
         (ac.operator_id = a.operator_id AND ac.facility_id IS NULL) OR
         (ac.operator_id = a.operator_id AND ac.facility_id = a.facility_id))
   )
ORDER  BY a.date, a.start_hour;
```

Most importantly, the boolean expression `ac.customer_id = ast.customer_id` is repeated in all three legs of the `OR`'ed expression. Break it out to simplify. That alone may be enough to arrive at a much more efficient query plan.

If `operator_id` and `facility_id` in `activity_schedule` are defined `NOT NULL`, you can simplify further:

```
...
   AND    ac.customer_id = :customer_id
   AND    ac.operator_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM a.operator_id
   AND    ac.facility_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM a.facility_id
...
```

The `SELECT` list of an `EXISTS` subquery can stay empty. `DISTINCT` does nothing useful there.

Indexes are on tables, not views. The info that `act.activity_schedule` is a view leaves us guessing.

Indexes on `(date)` and `(start_hour)` could help the query if it returned a large percentage of the whole table. And then a multicolumn index on `(date, start_hour)` would be *much* better.

Your filters look more selective than that, then the mentioned indexes are useless. You need indexes for the most selective filter(s). The query plan reveals there are some, but there is potential for optimization ...